# Storing an object in state after function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I apologize in advance for my bad language. Reading the question will take you no more than 30 seconds.

I have the following code:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            report: [],
            reports: [],
            donaters: [],
            donate_report: [],
            donaters_count: [],
            donaters_recurrent_count: [],
            dates: [],
            menu: [
                {
                    key: 2018,
                    title: "2019",
                    opened: true,
                    info: [
                        {
                            key: 11,
                            title: 'dec',
                            opened: false,
                            content: []
                        }, {
                            key: 10,
                            title: 'nov',
                            opened: false,
                            content: []
                        }, {
                            key: 9,
                            title: 'oct',
                            opened: false,
                            content: []
                        }]
                },
                {
                    key: 2019,
                    title: "2018",
                    opened: false,
                    info: [
                        {
                            key: 1,
                            title: 'jan',
                            opened: false,
                            content: []
                        }]
                }],
            active_menu: 2018,
            active_month: [],
            active_info: [],
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(value) {
        const {active_menu} = this.state;
        fetch(`${api.root}/donate_report?year=${active_menu}`, {param: value})
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((donate_report) => {
                this.setState({
                    report: donate_report.report[0].reports,
                    donaters: donate_report.report[0].donaters,
                    active_info: active_menu.info
                })
            })
    }


    toggleInfo(index) {
        const info = this.state.active_info.slice();
        info[index].opened = !info[index].opened;
        this.setState({
            active_info: info,
            active_month: info[index].key,
            dates: this.state.donaters[info[index].key][info[index].key + 1][0]
        })
    }

    toggleMenu(menu, value) {
        if (this.state.active_menu !== menu) {
            this.setState({active_menu: menu, mobile_menu_opened: false, menu_changed: true});
        fetch(`${api.root}/donate_report?year=${this.state.active_menu}`, {param: value})
                .then((response) => response.json())
                .then((donate_report) => {
                    this.setState({
                        report: donate_report.report[0].reports,
                        donaters: donate_report.report[0].donaters,
                        dates: donate_report.report[0].donaters[this.state.active_month][this.state.active_month + 1][0],
                        active_info: this.state.menu.info
                    });
                    console.log('update');
                });
        }
    }
```

Tell me, please, how can I store `info` from `menu` in `active_month` provided that `menu.key` is equal to `active_menu`

I have no problem assigning the selected menu to the state `active_menu` with my function `toggleMenu()` :

```
if (this.state.active_menu !== menu) {
            this.setState({active_menu: menu})
}
```

Sorry, if I wrote inaccurately, I will try to write in detail:

If the user chooses the year 2019, `active_menu` gets the key from the `menu` (For 2019 it is `2019` :)) And in the `active_month`, gets the whole `info` which in our case will be

```
{
key: 1,
title: 'jan',
opened: false,
content: []
}
```

Thanks for any of your answer and advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find menu item by key using. You can implement something like this:

```
   function getMenuInfoByKey (state, key) {
      let menuObj = state.menu.find(menuItem => menuItem.key === key);
      return menuObj && menuObj.info || null;
    }
```

and then you can easily use it `let selectedMenuInfoObj = getMenuInfoByKey(this.state, '2019')`